# Publishing to a self-contained file on Linux .NET Core

Tags: .net, .net-core

I have a discord bot I have built using [Discord.Net](https://github.com/discord-net/Discord.Net) - I have done this previously with the first version of the bot and not had any issues. I've done a version 2 with some upgrades and changes etc. however I can't get the bot to either publish within the Visual Studio IDE, I get the following:

```
    04/06/2021 17:44:03
    System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: Publish has encountered an error. We were unable to determine the cause of the error. Check the output log for more details. 
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    ---> (Inner Exception #0) Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: Publish has encountered an error. We were unable to determine the cause of the error. Check the output log for more details. <---
    
    Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: Publish has encountered an error. We were unable to determine the cause of the error. Check the output log for more details.
```

So I decide to upload the entire file to my Linux box and attempt to use `dotnet publish` on the box and instead get some errors that make a bit more sense.

```
    /root/bots/kards-bot/kards-bot.vbproj : error NU1605: Detected package downgrade: System.Diagnostics.Tracing from 4.3.0 to 4.1.0. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.  [/root/bots/kards-bot/kards-bot.sln]
    /root/bots/kards-bot/kards-bot.vbproj : error NU1605:  kards-bot -> Diff.Match.Patch 2.1.0 -> FSharp.Core 4.1.18 -> System.Net.Requests 4.0.11 -> System.Net.Primitives 4.0.11 -> runtime.unix.System.Net.Primitives 4.3.0 -> System.Diagnostics.Tracing (>= 4.3.0)  [/root/bots/kards-bot/kards-bot.sln]
    /root/bots/kards-bot/kards-bot.vbproj : error NU1605:  kards-bot -> Diff.Match.Patch 2.1.0 -> FSharp.Core 4.1.18 -> System.Net.Requests 4.0.11 -> System.Diagnostics.Tracing (>= 4.1.0) [/root/bots/kards-bot/kards-bot.sln]
    /root/bots/kards-bot/kards-bot.vbproj : error NU1605: Detected package downgrade: System.Diagnostics.Tracing from 4.3.0 to 4.1.0. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.  [/root/bots/kards-bot/kards-bot.sln]
    /root/bots/kards-bot/kards-bot.vbproj : error NU1605:  kards-bot -> Diff.Match.Patch 2.1.0 -> FSharp.Core 4.1.18 -> System.Net.Requests 4.0.11 -> System.Net.Http 4.1.0 -> System.IO.FileSystem 4.0.1 -> runtime.unix.System.IO.FileSystem 4.3.0 -> System.Buffers 4.3.0 -> System.Diagnostics.Tracing (>= 4.3.0)  [/root/bots/kards-bot/kards-bot.sln]
    /root/bots/kards-bot/kards-bot.vbproj : error NU1605:  kards-bot -> Diff.Match.Patch 2.1.0 -> FSharp.Core 4.1.18 -> System.Net.Requests 4.0.11 -> System.Diagnostics.Tracing (>= 4.1.0) [/root/bots/kards-bot/kards-bot.sln]
```

However I don't understand how its detected a package downgrade? I'm just publishing I'm not telling it to downgrade anything - I also don't understand why it has an issue with `Diff.Match.Patch` when it doesn't have any issue on the version 1 of the bot.

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question pretty quickly - added `System.Diagnostics.Tracing` via NuGet and selected V4.3.0. Looks like whatever is using it references v4.3.0 but doesn't package it.

Answer (score 0):

Use prarameter

```sh
--self-contained [true|false]
```

```sh
dotnet publish --self-contained=true
```

Reference document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish#options